# how to store starting stream position of each line of text file in c++?

Tags: c++, file

I'm getting some junk value instead of first character.
I think i have gone wrong in reading the stream position

```
string line;
int count=0;
streampos a[10];
fstream question("filename.txt");
while(!question.eof())
{
     a[count]=question.tellg();
     getline(question,line);
     count++;
 }
  //   cout<<count;
 int temp=0;char ch;
 while(temp<count)
 {
      question.seekg(a[temp++],ios::beg);
      question>>ch;
      cout<<ch<<endl;
 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5605159/1171191 - try `while(std::getline(question, line)) ...` and see where you go from there.

Comment: That's *a* problem, but are you sure it solves everything here?

Comment: u mean replace getline(question,line) with std::getline(question,line)?
didn't work though.

Comment: I'm not getting first position(character) of a line but some other character instead

Comment: No, I mean put the read into the `while` condition. Checking `eof` in a `while` is almost always wrong, as the duplicate explains.

Comment: tried that but i don't get first position(character).
I still get the same output(character) as earlier.